# How to animate curved area of a custom view?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, bezier

I'm setting up a custom Bézier view. I want to add some animation to the curved area, an animation like expansion/reveal effect to the curved area from plain area of the view.

I succeeded in creating a view by following the below link

https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7

Now I want to animate the curved area.

Few lines from custom view class

```
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
    mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
    mPath.close();
```

And in onDraw method

```
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

Comment: Good job with the drawing, now just make your draw call variables "variable". Suppose you want to flatten that bezier curve, use an animator to set your curve Y points to 0